# When I am using Python to generate an xml, even when I write very simple and short script, there is an error always when I am validate the xml file

Tags: python, xml

```
from xml.dom import minidom 
import os

root=minidom.Document()
xml=root.createElement('root')
root.appendChild(xml)

productChild=root.createElement('product')
xml.appendChild(productChild)
xml_str=root.toprettyxml(indent='\t')
save_path_file='test.xml'

with open(save_path_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(xml_str)
```

[image]

Comment: This is an issue with the app you're using to perform XML validation, not with Python.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve confused two different concepts here.  An XML document is *well-formed* when it obeys the syntax rules of XML. Your XML document is well-formed.

In order to be *valid* a document must have a grammar of some sort related to it.  The error message you are getting is caused by your missing grammar. The message says that there is no grammar rule defining the element.

I would encourage you to look at the Wikipedia entries for DTDs. They are fairly ancient tech but are the simplest form of grammar for an XML document. Creating a DTD allows you to validate a document.  It may be that for your purposes you don’t need a DTD. And well formed docs are OK.

There are other schema languages for XML you could alsO look at including W3C schemas and Schematron.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanation. So, Could I send the current XML document through a server?, is that possible?

Comment: That would depend on the server. If it requires a valid document, no. If it just requires well-formed XML, yes.